# How do I host my own Bazaar shared repositories?

Tags: bazaar, version-control

**What I want ?**

We operate in a small team of 9 people including developers, QA and designers. I want to setup a version control. We have a ubuntu (server edition) and i want to host all our repositories there. I have no understanding that even if it is possible.

**What I have done?**

We have setup bazaar on all distributions. We are using Bazaar explorer as our gui front-end. The command edition from console isn't very comfortable to all members. We have gone through the manual, but it hasn't been very helpful. Our inexperience being the cause.

**Team**

The designers are using windows distribution and developers & QA are using ubuntu distributions.

---

I have googled around and i am really struggling to find a good tutorial for this setup. So any links/guides/leads towards accomplishing the same would be very helpful.

While posting links or answer please do consider our **inexperience.**

Answer (score 1):

After using Google for 10 minutes, the best documentation I could find was

[Running a smart server](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/server.html)

*(Will update the answer as I find the better answer)*